# Why Google recommends using JPEG 2000 and JPEG XR and after Google Chrome doesn't support them?

Tags: google-chrome, jpeg, jpeg2000, jpeg-xr

Google recommends "[Serve Images in Next-Gen Formats](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/webp)" and specifically mentions WebP, JPEG 2000 and JPEG XR, but then it doesn't provide support for 2 of them ([JPEG 2000](https://caniuse.com/#feat=jpeg2000) and [JPEG XR](https://caniuse.com/#feat=jpegxr)) in **its own browser**.

Can someone please explain me why is this?

Answer (score 0):

This is because there is support for those formats in other browsers not just Google Chrome.  If all the users on the internet visited your website with Google Chrome then those formats would be insignificant to mention.

Comment: A briliant strategy. Use a image format, which will not be visible for 95% of users, but your page will load much faster. Briliant...

Comment: You use a combination of all 3 formats. Essentially, the browser picks which of the new formats it prefers, which is often substantially smaller than conventional .jpeg. Then the browser loads those more optimally compressed images, which results in faster page loads. https://www.imagecompress.org/examples