# Does Chrome support JPEG 2000 decoding?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, jpeg2000

Reading question on SO such as this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55568577/why-google-recommends-using-jpeg-2000-and-jpeg-xr-and-after-google-chrome-doesn), makes me wonder how Chrome can support PDF ≥ 1.7 (which can contains JPEG 2000 codestream), while at the same time claims that it does not support JPEG 2000:

- https://caniuse.com/jpeg2000

What is the trick here ?

Comment: Your question is specifically "how" Chrome can handle PDF files containing JPEG2000 images? Which is different from "Does Chrome support JPEG 2000 decoding?".

Comment: Engineering team implemented JPEG 2000 support, but only as an implementation detail for PDF rendering, and not for image handling ... which seems suprising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because PDFs in Chrome are rendered with [PDFium](https://opensource.google/projects/pdfium), which does support JPEG2000 while HTML is rendered using [Blink](https://www.chromium.org/blink), which does not.

The issue has already been discussed here:

- https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=776477

In particular [comment #4](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=776477#c4) makes the following observation:

> Chrome already has JPEG2000 support and includes openjpeg library for
> its PDF reader and has to deal with its fuzzing/security issues anyway
> so the actually supporting it like Safari is not opening a new attack
> surface and doesn't cost binary size also I'd guess.

Same goes [here](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/blink-dev/c/3CUPIGIKfOQ/m/mjP-8GvbBgAJ):

> PDF is not part of the standard web platform, it is a plugin, so it is
> out of scope. However, I agree with you that it seems silly to support
> this in one context and not in another.

Full thread on blink-dev:

- https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/blink-dev/c/3CUPIGIKfOQ/m/zzPakR6lBgAJ